# Where to find com.icesoft.spring.security.JsfRedirectStrategy class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

i am trying to apply the sample in here:

http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Spring+Security

but i need to know what library contains this class:

Code:

```
com.icesoft.spring.security.JsfRedirectStrategy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the attacted file: http://wiki.icefaces.org/download/attachments/2196309/SpringSecurity3IceFaces2-tutorial.zip
(in the `springsecurity/src/java/com/icesoft/spring/security` folder).

Unfortunately the link is on the top of the page.

Comment: where ? i downloaded the project but couldn't find it.

Comment: aha, thanks a lot i thought that it was a built in class, but seems that it's a custom class, how to import this project in eclipse by the way ?

Comment: You are welcome. I'd create a new Dynamic Web Project and copy the files into it. It looks an ant project, so you probably have to set dependencies, source folders etc by hand in Eclipse.